# How to save the content of custom array class and adapter in list view save into text in android

Tags: android-studio, android-listview, save, text-files

I need your help I am new in android programming. How can I save all the content in the list view save into text file this is my code of try to save the file but the problem is how can i put the listview array list to get the data i don't know how to put it where to put it please help how to do it to save the content of my listview

```
Button code:
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                            new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    for (int i = 0; i < ChatBubbles.length; i++) {
                        myOutWriter.append(ChatBubbles[i] +"\n");
                    }

                    myOutWriter.close();
                    fOut.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

Chatbubble class:
package com.example.ezminute;
public class ChatBubble {

    private String content;
    private boolean myMessage;

    public ChatBubble(String content, boolean myMessage) {
        this.content = content;
        this.myMessage = myMessage;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public boolean myMessage() {
        return myMessage;
    }
}

MessageAdapter:

    package com.example.ezminute;


public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatBubble> {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<ChatBubble> messages;

    public MessageAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<ChatBubble> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.activity = context;
        this.messages = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int layoutResource = 0; // determined by view type
        ChatBubble ChatBubble = getItem(position);
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

        if (ChatBubble.myMessage()) {
            layoutResource = R.layout.left_chat_bubble;
        } else {
            layoutResource = R.layout.right_chat_bubble;
        }

        if (convertView != null) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        //set message content
        holder.msg.setText(ChatBubble.getContent());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // return the total number of view types. this value should never change
        // at runtime. Value 2 is returned because of left and right views.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // return a value between 0 and (getViewTypeCount - 1)
        return position % 2;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView msg;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            msg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get an error message, show it. If it does it not work as expected, tell us what is happening and what you expect.

Comment: My expectation is i need to save all the content of the listview my listview design is like a bubble ui see my link sir https://www.google.com/search?q=chatbubble+ui&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8hIizm6ngAhWIwI8KHcNwBaUQ_AUIDigB&biw=1408&bih=688#imgrc=eSDcF88QSV0ieM:

Comment: i need to save the file as a text in the local storage of the android sir

Comment: D:\EzMinute2\app\src\main\java\com\example\ezminute\activities\convert_to_text.java:
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: sir i need your help please

Comment: Please add all clarification **to the question** instead of writing comments. I don't know if the warning is relevant to the problem, if you are unsure you should do what it tells you to do. It doesn't help to repeat what you already wrote in the question. What is happening in contrast to your expectation? What do you mean with "i cannot put the chatbubble class in the for loop"?

Comment: ok sir i just wanana put all the content in the listview and save it into a text file

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Did you try to implement what you want? Does it fail somehow? Don't you know how to implement it? **Please add all clarification to the question** instead of writing comments.

Comment: i updated the question sir